# Speed up reading images from file in Python

Tags: python

I found this code on web (see link in comment) and adapted it for my own purposes.

It is very slow. I have aprox 20K images to load.

How might I speed this up?

```
# https://medium.com/@ashok.tankala/build-the-mnist-model-with-your-own-handwritten-digits-using-tensorflow-keras-and-python-f8ec9f871fd3
# To load images to features and labels
def load_images_to_data(image_label, image_directory, features_data, label_data):
    list_of_files = os.listdir(image_directory)
    print('Load: '+repr(image_directory)+' Count: '+str(len(list_of_files)))
    for file in sorted(list_of_files):
        image_file_name = os.path.join(image_directory, file)
        if ".png" in image_file_name:
            img = Image.open(image_file_name).convert("RGB")
            im2arr=np.asarray(img)
            im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)
            if features_data.size ==0:
                features_data = im2arr
                label_data = [image_label]
            else:
                features_data = np.append(features_data, im2arr, axis=0)
                label_data = np.append(label_data, [image_label], axis=0)
    return features_data, label_data
```

Comment: If you are feeding those images into a machine learning machine, it might be useful to create a generator for images. The creation of the generator will not take any time, but of course during training you still need to load the images. See [the keras docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) regarding image preprocessing and loading.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa OK I will look at that in the future. For now, is there something faster than Image.open or is there an other inefficiency in this code?

Comment: Also `np.append` will likely be slower than using a `list`, `append`ing to that, and converting it to an `np.array` in the end.

Comment: You can see which part of your code is slowest by using a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html). The easiest one i just calling `python3 -m cProfile <yourcode.py>`. You should test it on a subset of your files.

Comment: I did not work with images much, but maybe scikit-image or Opencv are faster than PIL/pillow.